# Trying to recreate Microsoft's .net Asynchronous Client/Server Socket Example in UWP/C#

Tags: c#, sockets

I am trying to recreate Microsoft's .net examples for simple client/server communication in an c# uwp app. Later on I would like to send simple data from one app to another.

Asynchronous Client Socket Example
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-client-socket-example

Asynchronous Server Socket Example
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-server-socket-example

I haven't made any crucial changes but modified the ipHostInfo like this:

```
        IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost");
        ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
```

At first I implemented client and server class in the same app which was working fine (but of course useless) . Now when trying to separate client and server (1 app for the client example and 1 app for server example). The client is not able to connect to server. I successfully connected the client to some other listening ports (found in resource monitor) so problem must be the server which seams not to listen for connection requests from 'outside the own app'.

In resource monitor the server-app is shown in the 'Listening Ports' list as IPv4/IPv6 loopback, TCP protocol, firewall status: allowed, not restricted. (tried IPv4/v6 localhost)
I also added Private Networks (Client and Server) Capabilities in the manifest. 
Anyone an idea what might be the problem?

Comment: On the client, use: `IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Loopback; // or IPAddress.IPv6Loopback`, and on the server, use: `IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 11000); `

Comment: That is becuase, since the server example uses `IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName()); ` to get the host entry, this will return the name lookup for the name of your PC, and it will be the IP Address of your PC on the network. You cannot connect to a socket listening to say; 192.168.1.24 with your existing client code which uses the loopback address.

Comment: thanks for reply. 
The IP adress was not the issue. I checked the Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost").AdressList[] - name lookup first and chose the loopback IP 172.0.0.1 (resp. the ipv6 variant).  

I finally figured it out: 
Inbound loopbacks have to be explicitly enabled in regedit + running cmd/CheckNetIsolation.exe for UWP apps.  
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/develop-your-app/loopback) 

For testing this is fine but later on this is not very user-friendly. When app is in deployable state is there a method to avoid the running cmd/CheckNetIsolation.exe ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out: Inbound loopbacks have to be explicitly enabled in regedit + running cmd/CheckNetIsolation.exe for UWP apps.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/develop-your-app/loopback

Comment: No kidding.  You actually have to hack the registry to make this work?  Upvoting; this sounds like useful information.